# How to react when a child cried due to interaction with other children?

Tags: toddler, crying

When in a public library, another child who was older than my daughter came to and took a book from my daughter's hands, then my daughter started crying.

My daughter is 15 months old, cannot fully understand language yet, what should we do during / after this incident?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, I simply did what I felt would work best for my child to calm her down. Each child is different, so you will have to find what works best for your daughter. Since your child can’t understand language, you are unable to explain what happened or reassure her with words. Because of this, you should use actions to either distract her from the incident or smooth her. With my daughter, I would use small toys or a stuffed animal to distract her from an incident like this. She’d become focused on something entirely different and forget what originally made her upset. Since each child is different, this may not work for you. I’d suggest discovering what calms your child down and work with that.

Comment: In general this certainly makes sense but I wouldn't underestimate how much the child understands. Children understand language much sooner than they can produce it and 15 months old should be enough to try and explain things even if the baby won't understand fully. I would certainly try to reassure the baby with words along with any other actions.

Comment: @DRF:  Yes.  Even if the kid doesn't understand the words, she will get the tone of voice.  Besides, it's good practice to talk to the kid.